# Joints with custom kinematics that share the same configuration q

Tags: drake

I have a robot that consists of 3 links, `A` (this is the world/base frame), `B` and `C`.

I am working in a configuration space `q` that is different from the usual joint space of my robot.  This configuration space is not directly expressible as the result of a kinematic chain of standard joints supported by drake (I think?).

I have the forward kinematics that maps from `q` to the transformation matrix of each link of the robot, i.e.

```
T_AB = f(q)
T_AC = h(q)
```

I want to create a `MultibodyPlant` that represents this robot in this  configuration space.  More specifically, I want to be able to use it with `IrisInConfigurationSpace`.

### General way:  Create a custom joint that implements `Joint`

This seems like the most natural way.  The process would likely involve creating a `CustomJoint : Joint`, `CustomJointImpl : JointImpl`, `CustomJointMobilizer : Mobilizer`.

When creating the `MultibodyPlant`

```
joint1 = plant.AddJoint(CustomJoint(frameA, frameB))
joint2 = plant.AddJoint(CustomJoint(frameA, frameC))
```

However, one major difference is that these two joints share the same configuration space `q`.  It seems [`Mobilizer::position_start_in_q()`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/tree/mobilizer.h#L263-L266) does not allow for such sharing of configuration space?  I think it wouldn't be ideal to have a duplicate `q_bar = [q1, q2]` where `q1 == q2`?  I suppose I could only set this in the joint level by hard coding [`Joint::do_get_position_start()`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_joint.html#a2556aa7cb0dfde452bc41c8179ae9fe7) but I'm not sure if this will cause problems, since `Mobilizer::position_start_in_q()` is used in a few places, most notably, in [`MultibodyTree::MakeVelocityToQDotMap` and `MultibodyTree::MakeQDotToVelocityMap`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/tree/multibody_tree.cc#L1625-L1655).

Will this be an issue?

### Specific way (for `IrisInConfigurationSpace`) : Create a custom `SamePointConstraint`

Alternatively, AFAIK, the place in `IrisInConfigurationSpace` where the forward kinematics is needed is in the [`SamePointConstraint`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/geometry/optimization/iris_internal.cc#L13).  It seems creating a custom version of this would allow me to use my custom forward kinematics function for IRIS.

However, manually writing

```
void SamePointConstraint::DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const AutoDiffVecXd>& x, AutoDiffVecXd* y) const
```

seems daunting without the convenience functions provided by `MultibodyPlant` (and I'm not too familiar with `AutoDiff`)

---

So I'm not sure which method would be easier.  Any recommendations / alternatives are welcome.

Comment: Is it perhaps the case that your configuration space could be modeled using existing joints + constraints?  (like mimic joints, or coupler constraints?).  We have been adding support for these in multibodyplant... currently they are buried inside the SAP contact solver, but exposing those for IrisInConfigurationSpace (and other planning/control methods) is definitely on the roadmap.  Perhaps that would be a more elegant and sustainable generalization?

Comment: @RussTedrake I did in fact try a different formulation of configuration space that was compatible with existing joints + constraints but I was hoping to try different configuration space formulations to see which one Iris performs better in.

Comment: I see.  That's very reasonable.  I don't think the SamePointConstraint is what you want... the additional constraints passed to IrisInConfigurationSpace should have an interior.  Tommy Cohn has been working on generalizations of IRIS (and GCS) to support equality constraints -- it requires working on the manifold.  You might like his research blog here: https://blog.tommycohn.com/